# My emulator in android studio does not see my web services in visual studio with 10.0.2.2:xxxx

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, android-studio

I have web services running in my visual studio (it has its own web server if you run the code). The ip is localhost:xxxx.
Well, i know if i put 10.0.2.2 in a http request from my code in the emulator, i can reach localhost (that is IIS), it works well BUT, if i put 10.0.2.2:xxxx for reaching my integrated server in Visual Studio i can't reach it.

It's neccesary for me to do thi for debbuging my .net code, from an app that runs from the emulator in android studio.

Why i can see my IIS with 10.0.2.2 and not my Visual studio integrated server with 10.0.2.2:xxxx. Of course xxxx is the port. With postman i can send http request withoutplems to the 10.0.2.2:xxxx.

Thanks.

Comment: does your Android app have INTERNET permission?

Comment: Yes. And it can see mi iIS server in 10.0.2.2 but not my Visual studio running web services in 10.0.2.2:xxxx (ports).

Comment: probebly the problem is in the port? probebly it is reserved for some other service? Or probably VS embedded server does not allow connections from network? only from localhost?

Comment: I don't know if the port is the problem. It's not reserved for anything more, i can send http request from Postman without problem to localhost:xxxx (Visual Studio running web services). The last question... i don't know, it can be or not, i hope somebody can add some indications.